# Compare list of words with text and store the matched keyword to other column

Tags: r, loops, match

I want to loop through in a list of words and match these words with the text. And store the match word to another column. I tried with this example but it does not give me the required result.

```
text <- "crew reported during climb aircraft would not pressurize and elected to perform an air turn back to fll. crew also reported forward cargo door message at 200 feet"
text$Issues <- grepl(c("cargo door","aircraft","pressurize","malfunction"), text, ignore.case = TRUE)
```

It gives this result.

```
text                Issues
crew reported...    TRUE
```

And it only uses the 1st word from the list of words. I need to use a loop which goes one by one to each word and store the information but i need a data frame looks like this:

```
text                Issues
crew reported...    cargo door, aircraft, pressurize
```

Do I need to use any function? Any solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A possible option is using the function `stri_detect_regex` from the stringi package.

```
library(stringi)
text <- "crew reported during climb aircraft would not pressurize and elected to perform an air turn back to fll. crew also reported forward cargo door message at 200 feet"
keywords <- c("cargo door","aircraft","pressurize","malfunction")
paste0(keywords[stri_detect_regex(text, keywords, case_insensitive=TRUE)], collapse = ", ")

"cargo door, aircraft, pressurize"
```

`stri_detect_regex` will return `TRUE` or `FALSE` if it finds a keyword. Putting this inside the keywords will only return the found keywords. Wrapping it in `paste0` so it can be stored in a column if needed.

#### *edit added sapply version + better reproducible example:*

```
text <- c("crew reported during climb aircraft would not pressurize and elected to perform an air turn back to fll. crew also reported forward cargo door message at 200 feet",
           "cargo door malfunction because actor was pressing the open button during take off",
           "some more text",
           "and some more")

keywords <- c("cargo door","aircraft","pressurize","malfunction")

my_func <- function(x){
  paste0(keywords[stringi::stri_detect_regex(x, keywords, case_insensitive=TRUE)], collapse = ", ")
}
  
outcome <- sapply(text, my_func, USE.NAMES = FALSE)
outcome
[1] "cargo door, aircraft, pressurize" "cargo door, malfunction"          ""                                
[4] ""
```

Comment: I have more than one thousand different texts as I showed above (it is only one example) and same as texts I have a list of keywords with more than 200 words. If I use your suggestion on top of my data, it gives me the same keyword for all of the data (text) while each text string provides a different kind of words. Do you know how to solve it?

Comment: I added a better solution using sapply to return a vector of outcomes as long as the vector of texts.

Comment: Do you have any idea how to find the exact words in the text. Like; I have a list of words, and I want to find the exact words in the given text. The code above match those words as well which have some similarity. Any idea how to restrict the function with the particular word?